# How to update user's profile using mongo, passport and node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I'm creating a personal project. I choose Passport.js for authentifications and I would like to update user's profile using this mongoose schema :

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
local            : {
    email        : {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password     : {type: String, required: true}
},
first_name       : {type: String, required: true},
last_name        : {type: String, required: true},
username         : {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
email            : {type: String, required: true, unique: true}});
```

Here, the *post* route that I use :

```
app.post('/editProfile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next){
    User.update({ _id: req.user.id}, req.body, function(err, user){
        if(!user){
            req.flash('error', 'No account found');
            return res.redirect('/edit');
        }
        var emailEdit = req.body.email;
        var usernameEdit = req.body.username;
        var first_nameEdit = req.body.firstname;
        var last_nameEdit = req.body.lastname;
        if(emailEdit.lenght <= 0 || usernameEdit.lenght <= 0 || first_nameEdit.lenght <= 0 || last_nameEdit.lenght <= 0){
            req.flash('error', 'One or more fields are empty');
            res.redirect('/edit');
        }
        else{
            user.email = emailEdit;
            user.local.email = emailEdit;
            user.first_name = first_nameEdit;
            user.last_name = last_nameEdit;
            user.username = usernameEdit;

            res.redirect('/profile/');
        }
    });
```

When I run it, I have an error and I don't understand why

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'email' of undefined

because of `user.local.email = emailEdit;` When I comment this line, only username is updated.

I'm sure it's a stupid mistake that I did but I can't find it.

I'm also looking for an eventual much more efficient way to update profile using passport, node and mongo. And if possible a dynamic one which, for example, I could check in realtime if username is not already taken and set the field in red in this case.

Comment: Hm... why are you updating before validating? You normally validate before you update. And there's no such property as `lenght`.

Comment: @Mikey You're right I proceed to few changes. I will update. It works but I'm sure there is a more efficient way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Model.update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update)'s callback does not return a document.

In your case, I would just use `findById` and `save`.

```
app.post('/editProfile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next){

    User.findById(req.user.id, function (err, user) {

        // todo: don't forget to handle err

        if (!user) {
            req.flash('error', 'No account found');
            return res.redirect('/edit');
        }

        // good idea to trim 
        var email = req.body.email.trim();
        var username = req.body.username.trim();
        var firstname = req.body.firstname.trim();
        var lastname = req.body.lastname.trim();

        // validate 
        if (!email || !username || !firstname || !lastname) { // simplified: '' is a falsey
            req.flash('error', 'One or more fields are empty');
            return res.redirect('/edit'); // modified
        }

        // no need for else since you are returning early ^
        user.email = email;
        user.local.email = email; // why do you have two? oh well
        user.first_name = firstname;
        user.last_name = lastname;
        user.username = username;

        // don't forget to save!
        user.save(function (err) {

            // todo: don't forget to handle err

            res.redirect('/profile/');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const updateUser = (req ,res, next)=>{
    const updateData = req.body.update;
    if (!updateData){
        res.status(422).send({"message":"please provide what you want to update"})
    }
    User.findOne({email:req.body.user.email}).then(function(user) {
        if (!user) { return res.sendStatus(401); }

        //NOTE  only update fields that were actually passed...
        if (typeof updateData.username !== 'undefined') {
            user.username = updateData.username;
        }
        if (typeof updateData.email !== 'undefined') {
            user.email = updateData.email;
        }
        if (typeof updateData.first_name !== 'undefined') {
            user.email = updateData.email;
        }
        if (typeof updateData.last_name !== 'undefined') {
            user.email = updateData.email;
        }
        if (typeof updateData.bio !== 'undefined') {
            user.bio = updateData.bio;
        }
        if (typeof updateData.image !== 'undefined') {
            user.image = updateData.image;
        }
        if (typeof updateData.password !== 'undefined') {
            user.setPassword(updateData.password);
        }
        return user.save()
            .then(function() {
                return res.json({ user: user.toAuthJSON() });
            });
    }).catch(()=>{
        res.status(422).send({"message":"couldn't update user"})
    }
    );
};
UserSchema.methods.generateJWT = function() {
var today = new Date();
var exp = new Date(today);
exp.setDate(today.getDate() + 60);
return jwt.sign({
    id: this._id,
    username: this.username,
    exp: parseInt(exp.getTime() / 1000),
}, config.secret);
```

};

```
UserSchema.methods.toAuthJSON = function() {
return {
    username: this.username,
    email: this.email,
    token: this.generateJWT(),
    bio: this.bio,
    avatar: this.image
};
```

};

Comment: Give some details also please.